# Can I remap controller keys to different actions?

Tags: ps4, need-for-speed-2015

In Need For Speed on PS4, there seem to be 2 fixed input schemes for the controller, based on whether the car is using automatic or manual gears. However, I can't find any option to actually customize the inputs such as change the button used for acceleration etc.

Is there a way to do this, preferably thru the game itself or if it does not allow this, is there a workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the game itself has no control remapping options, the workaround is to use the system Accessibility settings to remap your controller.

Setting > Accessibility > Button Assignments

Comment: Its too bad that joystick (for gear changes) can't be remapped for keys on PS4 afaik, but its still good to know this option for button remapping.